# How to show 404 Error Page in React Router V6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am using React for my webapp frontend . But during development , i came across routing problem in react-router-dom V6 . That problem is i would like to show 404 error page if none of the routes is matched . Here is my code ,

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter,Routes,Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from "./Pages/Home"
import Allposts from './Pages/Allposts'
import Createpost from './Pages/Createpost'
import Error404 from './Pages/Error404'

const App = () => {
    return(
        <>
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Routes>
                <Route path="/" element={<Home />}/>
                <Route path="/all-posts" element={<Allposts />}/>
                <Route path="/create-post" element={<Createpost />} />
                <Route path="*" element={<Error404 />} />
            </Routes>
        </BrowserRouter>
        </>
    )
}

export default App;
```

As you can see i have added catch all routes Route at the end with path equal to "*" mark . This catches all routes except the nested routes (and this is the problem ) . By general rule , it should catch all routes whether that is nested or not nested and it should display that 404 error page component . When i am using route "localhost:3000/all-posts/12345" <--- as this route is not present it should display that 404 error page component instead of showing this it shows a just blank page and an error pops out in console saying resource not found with an error of 404 that's it .

This is the problem . How to solve this problem and show 404 error page component .

Comment: What nested routes are your referring to? Please include all relevant code you are working with and have issues using. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: What **exactly** is the error reported in the console?

Answer (score 3):

If you could switch to this method, it would work for all the nested components as well.

```
import { createBrowserRouter, RouterProvider } from 'react-router-dom';

function Error404() {
  return <h2>404 Not found</h2>;
}

const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: '/',
    errorElement: <Error404 />,
    children: [
      {path: '', element: <Home /> },
      {path: 'all-posts', element: <Allposts /> },
      {path: 'create-post', element: <Createpost /> },
    ],
  },
]);

function Router() {
  return (
    <RouterProvider router={router} />
  );
}

export default Router;
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi did you try ?

Try this

```
<Switch>
   <Route path='*' component={Error404} />
</Switch>
```

Answer (score 0):

react can't check on it's own if the post exists or not,
you can put a simple check like this to handle it

```js
if (post exists) {
  return <Post/>; //render Post info/details
} else {
  return <Error404 />; // if not redirect to 404
}
```